# How to get results from WEKA

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I understand how to use WEKA APIs I first load the `arff` into the program which creates `Instances`. These will then be given to a `Classifier` that has been trained on this Dataset. Now I want to give it a new test dataset without a label and make the WEKA API tell me what the label for that instance is or may be. How is that done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use Classifier.classifyInstance(Instance)

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html

Comment: What is this double value the method is returning? Is it the index of the class predicted?

Comment: @Prometheus87 Classifier.classifyInstance(Instance) will return a double that corresponds to Instance.classValue (the internal representation of a class).  There is a good tutorial here: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code

Answer (score 0):

Your training and test instances should look exactly the same.

feature value 1, feature value 2......., feature value n, class value
feature value 1, feature value 2......., feature value n, class value

When you are applying your model on your test set, Weka will not provide your model the class value of the instances. Rather it will ask, "hey, classifier, let me see how you assign classes to each of the test instances as you learned from training set". Then the classifier model assigns each test instance a class from what it learned from training set. Weka then compares it and provides result in terms of precision, recall, f-score, ROC, AUC, errors, etc. So, in summary, your test instance will have the class values. Don't exclude that. Otherwise, you will get an error like "training and test sets are incompatible".

Comment: hi. I have trained my classifier but now passing the `Instance` is a problem. I have like 100 numeric features in one instance and one string character as label or class. I can't initialize my instance. you see the constructor is `Instance(double weight, double[] attrValues)` and now an `weka.core.UnassignedDatasetException` is being thrown on the classify instance and it says that Instance doesn't have access to a dataset. I can't add the 101th attr i.e. the string character to the attrValues[] since it is of type `double` What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the problem was that I was not assigning any data on the new `Instance`. That had to be done by `Instance.setData()` and you will then pass the Instances object with which the Classifier was trained